# Trying to create an npm package with a NextJS localFont but get 'is not a function' error when using the package

Tags: npm, next.js

I have created a font in my `typography` package like so:

```
import localFont from "next/font/local";

const circularFont = localFont(
    {
        src:"../lib/font/circular/CircularXXWeb-Medium.woff2",
        weight: "500",
        variable: "--font-circular"
    }
);

export {circularFont};
```

Building it with this npm script:

```
"build": "rm -rf dist && babel src/index.ts --out-dir dist --extensions '.ts,.tsx' && tsc --p tsconfig.emit.json && mv dist/index.js dist/index.mjs && sass lib/puls-fonts-next.scss:dist/typography-next.css lib/puls-fonts.scss:dist/typography.css --no-source-map"
```

I have next as a `peerDependency` in my typography/package.json.

When I try to use it in my Next app like so in `_app.js`:

```
...other imports
import { circularFont } from "@dips/puls-typography/dist";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return <SystemProvider>
        <div className={`${circularFont.variable} puls-docs-wrapper`}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </div>
    </SystemProvider>;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Server Error
TypeError: next_font_local__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ is not a function

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source
..\typography\dist\index.mjs (2:19) @ eval

  1 | import localFont from "next/font/local";
> 2 | var circularFont = localFont({
    |                 ^
  3 | src: "../lib/font/circular/CircularXXWeb-Medium.woff2",
  4 | weight: "500",
  5 | variable: "--font-circular"
```

`index.mjs` is the output from the build command I ran earlier and looks like this:

```
import localFont from "next/font/local";
var circularFont = localFont({
  src: "../lib/font/circular/CircularXXWeb-Medium.woff2",
  weight: "500",
  variable: "--font-circular"
});
export { circularFont };
```

What am I doing wrong here? Something I'm not getting correctly